# Saying hello to a mixed-gender group

Tags: classical-latin

If you were greeting a mixed-gender group, what would have been the most common way to do this in classical era Rome? Would they have said something like *salvete amici et amicae*, or would they have only used the masculine noun?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Classical Latin, like in many of the older Indo-European languages, the masculine was very much a "default" gender. (The feminine was a relatively late development within Proto-Indo-European, and it took a few more millennia for it to become as common and well-established as the masculine.) So a group of friends of mixed gender would be, by default, ***amīcī***.

If you don't want to use a gendered form, though, you could also use a word like *socius* ("comrade"), which is *epicene*—it can refer to people of any gender, but is always grammatically masculine. So a group of comrades, no matter what their genders might be, would always be ***sociī***.

Comment: Salvete omnes worked for Doctor Illa Flora.

Comment: @livresque That's fine until you need an adjective.  Then *socii* would be better.